# Is multilevel analysis with aggregation terms the best approach for this situation?

Tags: modeling, multilevel-analysis

My research model has two levels of dependent variable, at the organizational level and a predictor variable at individual level. I have 500 answers from 5 middle managers (in each firm) in 100 firms at an individual level and 200 from 2 top managers (in each firm) from the same 100 firms.

My question is whether aggregation of each data set and using mean score in regression is the best option? If yes, what are the aggregation terms? If not what other option or software is the best to fit this model?

Comment: Why not use multilevel analysis? If you aggregate you lose the variation in the data that you aggregated.

Comment: Ahmad, it would help to be more specific about precisely what you would like to predict.  But Peter's suggestion is almost certainly good.  Multilevel models also go by names like "mixed models" or "hierarchical models."  Most statistical software can fit some of these types of models.

Comment: Thanks Peter and Michael. I wanna to test the influence of some organizational factors and knowledge sharing at individual level and community level on innovation at organizational level with presence of a moderator btv org factors & KS. How to run the test with two different sets of data ( 500 middle managers and 200 top managers) in SPSS for e.g. , this is the part I have issue. Appreciate your advise.